Incorrect window sizes
The Issue
tl;dr: All of my application windows seem to be 14px too narrow and 7px too short.
I'm currently programming a desktop application with a fixed size of 1024px wide by 768px high. I took a screenshot of the application with greenshot and the dimensions of it read "1010px by 761px".
"This looks odd, I wonder if I can reproduce it". And reproduce it I could.
I created the same basic application using a couple of different frameworks (Wails, Electron, Windows Forms) and they all have the same issue - 14px too narrow and 7px too short.
"This can't be!" I exclaimed and so I contacted a couple of friends running different Windows versions, sent them the executables and they all responded with the same result: The application window (including the title bar) is 14px too narrow and 7px too short.
This only happens in a regular bordered window btw. Having a borderless window gives the correct size.
DPI scaling also doesn't seem to be the issue - I have it set to 100%. A friend has it at 125% but when normalizing his result, the application was still 14px too narrow and 7px too short.
The Question
Is this a known bug in Windows? Is there a hidden setting somewhere that scales stuff weirdly?
Example Screenhot


@NickSlash I'm taking a screenshot of the application using a tool called Greenshot. It displays the resolution of the screenshot while taking the screenshot. I'll add it as an example to my question.

I wonder if the screenshot tool is leaving out window borders of some flavour

Yes, or perhaps not accommodating for the size of scrollbars.

@JourneymanGeek i thought so, too. As a different measure, I created a scene in OBS with the desired dimensions. If the window has the right size and greenshot is the issue, it should still fit. But when I added the window to the scene, it didn‘t quite fill the whole scene, being a tiny bit too small

Looking at the wailsapp GitHub issues page, it seems this is known and not necessarily a bug.
https://github.com/wailsapp/wails/issues/3260
Window size is the parent window and not the webview that displays your app, so includes the frame and title bar.
Try running with frameless=true and see what the size is reported as.
If you don't want to implement your own frame, just calculate the difference between actual and expected and update the size with the differences.

I‘m already aware of the issue on the Wails Github, but I also tested this with other frameworks (like Electron or Windows Forms) and they all had the same discrepancies

Because they all have window frames as explained in that thread? Did you try running it frameless?

Yes, I tried running it frameless - the size was as expected then. Running it frameless is, however, not what I want :/
